# Is there a way to generate asciidocs from application.properties in Quarkus?

Tags: documentation, quarkus, documentation-generation

Is there a way to automatically generate asciidocs from application.properties in Quarkus?
lets say i have an application.properties with the following keys

```
quarkus.lambda.expected-exceptions
quarkus.lambda.handler
```

I want to generate docs like the quarkus config documentation like so.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d61X1.png)

Comment: Quarkus extensions do this already automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe quarkus extension can do smth like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).